# Why am I receiving Cannot read property 'state' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a constructor that suddenly stopped working, can't figure out why.

I have this data. If you see at line 24, this is read out and actually returns various items including props. However 1 line later when I try to write to state, it returns this error. I can't figure out why as there's nothing to bind here and it was working at some point.

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
>  23 | super(props);
>  24 | console.log(this)
>  25 | 
>  26 | this.state = {
>     | ^  27 |   loading: true,
>  28 |   ...props.location.state,
>  29 |   review: props.review,
> ```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
import { AuthUserContext } from '../Session';

import { needsEmailVerification } from '../Session/withEmailVerification.js'

import NewCommentReactionPage from '../Comments/newReaction.js'
import NewReviewFeedbackPage from '../Comments/new.js'
import RequireEmailComponent from '../Errors/requireEmail.js'

const ReviewFeedbackPage = (props) => (
  <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser => (
        <ReviewFeedbackMain authUser={authUser} isLoggedIn={condition(authUser)} needEmail={needsEmailVerification(authUser)} {...props} />
    )}
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);

class ReviewFeedbackBase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      ...props.location.state,
      review: props.review,
      newComment: '',
      comments: [],
      reactions: props.review ? props.review.count ? props.review.count.reactions ?  props.review.count.reactions : {} : {} : {}
    };

    this.reactionAdded = this.reactionAdded.bind(this)
    this.commentAdded = this.commentAdded.bind(this)
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    ...  
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    ...
  }


  commentAdded(newComment){
 ...
 }

  render() {
    const { review, comments, reactions } = this.state;
    const { isLoggedIn, needsEmail } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
       ....
        }
        {isLoggedIn && needsEmail && <RequireEmailComponent toAction={{text: 'to react'}} />}
        {isLoggedIn && !needsEmail &&
          <div>
            <NewCommentReactionPage review={review} reactionAdded={this.reactionAdded} />
            <NewReviewFeedbackPage review={review} commentAdded={this.commentAdded} />
          </div>
        }


      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ReviewFeedbackMain = withFirebase(ReviewFeedbackBase);

const condition = authUser => !!authUser;
export default ReviewFeedbackPage;
```

Comment: Please show the code of your component

Comment: Just added, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have 2 `state`:

```
this.state = {  // declaring state
  loading: true,
  ...props.location.state,  // referencing the state of ...props.location
  review: props.review,
  newComment: '',
  comments: [],
  reactions: props.review ? props.review.count ? props.review.count.reactions ?  props.review.count.reactions : {} : {} : {}
};
```

You are getting this error because `props.location` is `undefined` and you are trying to access `state` from it.

The error is in line 26 because it's not being able to declare the variable.

> ```
> 26 | this.state = {
>    | ^  27 |   loading: true,
> ```

Not a problem in the constructor, but in the `...props.location.state`.

Now that you know what is the problem, you need to see what you want to do.

Maybe do some checking before spreading `props.location.state` ? It's up to you.

Comment: Wow awesome find! That was an outdated piece of code anyway. Got rid of it and problem went away... wow, just wow. Thank you.